# How do you run tests in parallel using robot framework? Issues with Parallel Library

Tags: robotframework

The below is the code present in parallel_tests.txt

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Parallel  

*** Test Cases ***
Runner
    Run Parallel Tests  Hello   World

Hello
    [Tags]  parallel
    Log     Hello123 

World
    [Tags]  parallel
    Log     World123
```

I am trying to execute this test case file 
from terminal using jybot as below:
jybot parallel_tests.txt;

I am getting the following error:
No keyword with name 'Run Parallel Tests' found.

How to execute both test cases Hello and World ,in parallel in robot framework using parallel library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly different use case but have you tried using [pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot)?

I haven't gone down the rabbit hole with this one so don't have an in-depth understanding but I do use it for cross-browser tests via sauceLabs.  It will work differently from how you want in that it does parallel runs but by test suite rather than test case level.  Perhaps this is configurable?  Unfortunately as mentioned I just know enough to get it working for my needs and haven't done a deep dive.

Any questions let me know and I'll try to help.

Here's a quick example as requested, I've stripped lots of our stuff which is useless in your case but left some in so you can see how to build up.  I changed the processes parameter from %processes% to 2, the end result is the same, in my case these values are coming from a teamcity build configuration:

```
pabot --processes 2 --variable environment:%environment% --name OS_X_10.9-Firefox --variable browser:%browser% --listener robot-tc-listener --include %includetags% --exclude %exclusiontags% --outputdir %PabotResults_DIR% --output output.xml --report report.html --log log.html tests
```

Comment: Any example test case how to use pabot for testing?

Comment: As Part of the requirement ,we need to write libraries in java and export as jar and use the functions as keywords in robot framework.I am new to robotframework..and one more question , Pabot works with python and jython both? because i have installed robot framework using jython..so when i did pip install robotframwork-pabot and execute pabot am getting error stating error while importing multiprocessing

Comment: Have you actually read the link I included? https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot - it contains several examples of its use.  I don't get what you mean by for testing, pabot's sole function is the execution of robot tests in parallel, there is no other use for it.  Decided to edit the answer to include an example, please actually try to solve the issue yourself, read the docs and if you have further questions, then ask for help and supply as much detail as possible

Comment: Being a newbie to robotframework, I was not sure if this a obvious question..Thanks for your help!

Comment: Parallel library was an experiment that we did long long time ago while I was part of RF core development. I wouldn't use it for anything as the logic how it works is fairly odd and I bet it won't even work with current RobotFramework.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of RobotFramework are you using? The Parallel library was removed in `2.5` (see [this ticket](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/490), though there may be distant plans of [reintroducing it](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1792)).

I tried to reproduce your issue using [this file](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/proto/parallel/Parallel.py?r=86ca36b0d6dfacb3947d7988a447cadb5e873d75) with RF version 2.8, but there are several compatibility problems, as expected.

Are you sure that the library has been loaded properly? When it fails, in addition to the error, you will also get a message telling you that the keywords are unavailable.

Comment: I tried using latest 2.9 version also the trunk 20140617

Comment: Ok - then I would not expect it to work. You already had to adapt the `Parallel.py` file to make it compatible with RF 2.9. Since they dropped the support, and that it was not working as intended before, I would think that the `pabot` suggestion of @shicky seems indeed to be your best bet.